# How to select redundant rows

Tags: postgresql

Suppose a table `data` recording values of some `foo` and `bar` over time:

```
time | foo | bar
-----+-----+----
1    | a   | a
2    | a   | a
3    | a   | a
4    | B   | a
5    | B   | a
6    | a   | a
7    | a   | a
8    | a   | X
...
```

We would like to select the duplicate rows in order to get rid of them. Duplicate rows are, in this example, those with times **2**, **3**, **5** and **7**, because the tuple `(foo, bar)` did not change from the previous time. Also, while the row **6** seems to be duplicate of **1**, **2** and **3**, there is a change in between, thus **6** is not a duplicate (but **7** is).

My simple solution is this:

```
SELECT 
  *
FROM 
  data AS candidate
WHERE 
  EXISTS (
  SELECT 
    * 
  FROM 
    data AS original
  WHERE 
    ROW(candidate.foo, candidate.bar) IS NOT DISTINCT FROM ROW(original.foo, original.bar)
    AND original.time < candidate.time
    AND NOT EXISTS (
      SELECT
        *
      FROM
        data AS other
      WHERE
        ROW(candidate.foo, candidate.bar) IS DISTINCT FROM ROW(other.foo, other.bar)
        AND original.time < other.time
        AND other.time < candidate.time
    )
  )
```

In human language: looking for rows where we can find a row above it with the same `(foo, bar)`, but where there is no other row with some other `(foo, bar)` in between.

Is there some feature of PostgreSQL that could be used for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are many ways for doing this.

#### When measurements can be trusted to be sequential (`time`), then one can use a simple self left join, which should perform very fast:

```
SELECT *
FROM data d
LEFT JOIN data prev ON (prev.time = d.time - 1)
WHERE (d.foo, d.bar) IS DISTINCT FROM (prev.foo, prev.bar)
```

#### Another one is using window functions (PG version >= 8.4):

```
SELECT time, foo, bar
FROM (
  SELECT *, lag(foo) over () AS prev_foo, lag(bar) over () AS prev_bar
  FROM data
  ) d
WHERE (foo, bar) IS DISTINCT FROM (prev_foo, prev_bar)
```

#### And another option is using a recursive CTE (PG version >= 8.4):

```
WITH RECURSIVE d(time, foo, bar) AS (
  SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY time LIMIT 1) a
  UNION ALL
  SELECT *
  FROM (
    SELECT data.*
    FROM data, d
    WHERE data.time > d.time AND (data.foo, data.bar) IS DISTINCT FROM (d.foo, d.bar)
    ORDER BY data.time
    LIMIT 1) a
)
SELECT * FROM d
```

Comment: Good points. The `time` values are in my case unfortunately just timestamps, thus no sequence. The window functions look great though! Thanks.